# What kind of paint should I choose to start painting?

Tags: painting

To start painting what paint should I choose? Oil, acrylic, or another?
I use pencils now, and would like to upgrade to colors.

Comment: Hi, CIMend, and welcome to Arts & Crafts. Your question is overly broad, can you specify what you're trying to achieve? Are you working on a particular project? The logical next step in moving from what I assume are grey pencils to colours would be coloured pencils. Why do you want to try paints?

Comment: Not coloured pencils! In future i would like to paint more artistic

Comment: I was thinking in Acrilic, for all i ve been findind

Comment: You write "I use pencils now, and would like to upgrade to colors". So I wondered why you want to start painting, as the *logical* next step - from grey pencils to colours - would be coloured pencils. The rest of your comments don't make sense to me: "painting more artistic(ly?)" has nothing to do with what you're asking in your question (if you want to start using paint because you think it will allow for a more artistic approach, you should specify that), and if you were already thinking of acrylic, you might want to add why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you would like/enjoy to get involved in. A lot is based on opinion where to start. As a child, I started with watercolor. For some artists, they say that watercolor is more difficult because of how fluid it is, and how it spreads compared to other paints. Making it more difficult to control for a first-timer.

Acrylic could be a good start, because it is easy to dry, and you can get more done with acrylic paint, over a short amount of time. Compared to oil paint, that will take a longer time to dry. I have found with oil paint, it is beautiful ability to blend colors, compared to acrylic or watercolor. Oil paint can be very messy for a beginner paint.

It really depends on what you would enjoy. I found enjoyment in all three paints, but each one is kind of their own kind of technique and ability.

From personal preference only have found mine to be from easiest.

1)Watercolor.
Pros: fluid colors, dries fast.
Cons: Could spread to other colors and ripping paper from getting damp.

2)Acrylic. 
Pros: Fast drying, can make layers fast.
Cons: Not as well blended colors.

3)Oil paint. 
Pros: Blends well, combines colors well.
Cons: Takes forever to dry, messy, and if you aren't careful could get on clothing and stain.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with acrylic paint. It’s not too expensive and also doesn’t take months to dry/, versus oil paints.. which are pricey, messy and takes a long time to dry.

Comment: Obrigado ! I ve alredy the paintings to paint

Comment: You’re welcome :) I hope you make something beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend watercolor. I started on them and the paper can be used on both sides if you get good quality. Blending is easy to do and you can easily control the color's intensity.